# How to import objects outside of src in scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

How to import say the objects present in project level, say Dependencies?

Comment: You can't. Your project code and your meta-project code are two different spaces. It would be better if you can explain to us why you need that, what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Your project (`build.sbt`) and build project (`project/build.sbt`) are independent.

You can try to add an additional source directory to your project

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+source+directory